# Changing the woocommerce default tax country location

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

WooCommerce only allows calculating tax based on billing/shipping address and shop base (and geolocation), however I want to manually set the default tax location for new visitors that have not selected a country yet, to a static country without altering base shop address.

The reason I do not want to alter base shop address, is because I believe it will potentially affect plugins using it to show a base address, which wouldn't be correct anymore based as this tax country location.

I tried using the hook;

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_tax_location', 'customer_default_tax_location', 20, 3 );
function customer_default_tax_location( $location, $tax_class = '', $customer = null ) {
    if ( ! is_null( $customer ) && is_null( $customer->get_shipping_country() ) && is_null( $customer->get_billing_country() ) ) {
        return ['NL', null, '', ''];
    }
    return $location;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_default_location', 'customer_default_location', 10, 1 );
function customer_default_location( $location ) {
    return "NL";
}
```

However this poses an issue because $customer->get_shipping_country/get_billing_country() will always return a country even if the visitor has not yet created a session yet, so this won't work. Is there a way to check if the customer has not yet specified or selected a country on cart or checkout (or logged in)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet alone should do the trick. $customer is already not null as get_tax_location() checks that already.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_tax_location', 'bbloomer_customer_default_tax_location', 9999, 3 );

```
function bbloomer_customer_default_tax_location( $location, $tax_class, $customer ) {
    if ( ! $customer->get_shipping_country() && ! $customer->get_billing_country() ) {
        return array( 'NL', '', '', '' );
    }
    return $location;
}
```